# Git commit only commits part of change to one file

Tags: git, bitbucket

The past few days I have been having the strangest GIT problem. We are using Bitbucket, and I make a change to a file. Maybe change 2 or more lines while in my IDE. After making those changes I do a commit and only part of those lines get committed.

Example:

Say original code is

```
public void doSomething() {
    println "Hello";
    println "World";
}
```

and then say I change it to

```
public void doSomething() {
    println "Bonjour";
    println "Monde";
}
```

The I do a commit and push. I look at the commit after and it now has the code as

```
public void doSomething() {
    println "Hello";
    println "Monde";
}
```

or Maybe

```
public void doSomething() {
    println "Bonjour";
    println "World";
}
```

Anyone experience that before, know how to stop it from happening?

Comment: Could you include the commands you used to stage and commit?

Comment: Probably You havn't saved the file. Behaviour you describe is also possible with some git commands but I doubt you use them.

Comment: A commit saves a snapshot of the file. If the file is “wrong” in a particular commit, you did not add it correctly or the file was not saved.

Comment: Do a git diff before you commit to see whats changed in the file according to git and a normal diff to see if something's different.

Comment: Thanks you for the great responses. I actually am using IntelliJ IDEA and going to the saved files list that have changes and the changes are there and saved. Then I right click on that list and select Commit and Push. So a git diff is as simple as right clicking on a file in the change list and choosing "Show Diff" which does a git diff. In all cases the changes are made to the file. In regards to my latest change, that was my fault. The others were Jasper reports where it also saved because the date change of the file in its xml committed but the change that causes that wasn't - same file